# Print image with specific width & height

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I want to upload an image to print with some `string` values when I try to print I can't specify the width & height of the image. I want to display it like a header of the page and give it constant width & height.

Below is the code of uploading the image:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imageLocation = dialog.FileName;

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imageLocation;
            //pictureBox1.Image.Width(100);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The printing code:

```cs
e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation), e.PageBounds);

e.Graphics.DrawString(labelProjectNum.Text,
    new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Underline),
    Brushes.Black,
    new Point(700, 200));

e.Graphics.DrawString(projectNumber.Text,
    new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular),
    Brushes.Black,
    new Point(650, 200));
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `Width` and `Height` of `e.PageBounds`?

Comment: This way your image will cover the total area of the page which the [PageBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.pagebounds?view=netframework-4.8) property returns. You should pass a drawing rectangle like : `e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation), new Rectangle(e.PageBounds.X,e.PageBounds.Y,imgWidth,imgHeight));` where the `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` your constant width and height as you mentioned.

Comment: Also check, [PrintPageEventArgs.MarginBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.marginbounds?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to print inside the margins.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `e.PageBounds` you can put a `rectangle`

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation), new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
```